# How to deploy Er REST Example on cc2650 platform

Tags: contiki, coap

I am working on cc2650 and cc2531 dongle and I have already installed 6lbr. Now I need to check security for CoAP  and I need to implement a simple example. I want to work on Er-REST example and I have some questions regarding to deployment.

1)Do I have to also use Cooja? I am asking I am using the native-border-router together with the slip-radio. So which settings should I have done to be able to deploy the example?

There are how to's for other platforms but not slip radio cc2650.

Is there anyone who worked on or do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the TMOTES HOWTO in https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/examples/er-rest-example

It should be the same concept to what you want.

Be careful with what "native" platform means: check this link https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Native%2C-minimal-net

Comment: I cannot comment except on my own post, so please open another question if you may.